# link from one html page to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/skhare/myFirstStyleSheet.css">

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').click(showTables(a){                
                        alert(a);
    });
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>s
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
          $.getJSON('/Users/skhare/reportSuiteList.json',   function(reportSuiteList) {
    var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
    output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "id" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "name" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "stage" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "DWH" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
    for (var i in reportSuiteList.suites)
    {
        output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_ID + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<a href=# id = name onClick = showTables(reportSuiteList.suites[i].name>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME + "</a>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].STAGING_DATABASE + "</td>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].DWH_DATABASE + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    }

        output+="</table>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
```

});

```
</body>
</html>
```

i am getting the error as missing ) after argument list.i checked it but my (,{ appear to be balanced and i can't make out where i am missing the ).
Please help

Comment: check your code, I think you have missed '}' for function `function(reportSuiteList) {`.

Comment: i rechecked my code but it still give me the same error. i executed both the <scripts> element separately before and it ran fine but i need the top script on click event of second script so i tried to merge them and since then i am getting the error. Please help as i am new to jQuery

Comment: After you make changes to Js or jQuery code, sometimes even after refreshing the screen the latest changes won't show up. You need to clear browser cookies. Try this and update your latest code here.

Comment: i cleared my cookies. Please tell me how to paste the code as am unable to do so on the comment space

Comment: my list is as follows 
A
B
C

if i click A then some data should be loaded from file A.json and click B then from B.json, etc.

Comment: Hi Sonal, I still can't see the `}` for the `function(reportSuiteList)`. Did you tried this? Also there is no need to import the jQuery library twice in your  code.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not necessary, and `window.location.replace(...)` will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

It is better than using `window.location.href` =, because `replace()` does not put the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco. If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use location.href. If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace.`

For example:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```